# Getting the content of a table td in console

Tags: javascript

This is proving surprisingly tricky. Attached is a screen of what I want from the DOM:

[image]

I want the innerHTML (Or at least I thought I did) of the td with class product-price.

Here's another screen of all the stuff I've tried and the output:
[image]

How do I get the console to return $59.99? Important it comes from the first element not the second where 59.99 also exists

Following a comment, here is the broader html:

```
<table cellspacing="1" class="store_location_list">


            <tr>
                <th class="item-type">Item<br />Type</th>
                <th class="item-desc">Item<br />Description</th> 
                <th class="total-qty">Total<br />Quantity</th>
                <th class="product-price">Product<br/>Price</th>
                <th class="total-price">Total<br/>Price</th>
                <th class="removeItemLink"> </th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="item-type">Metal Wall Art</td>
                <td class="product-description-long">Metal Wall Art</td>
                <td class="total-qty">1</td>

         <!-- ************************************** -->       
                <td class="product-price">$59.99</td>
                <td class="total-price">$59.99</td>
                <td class="removeItemLink"><a href="#" onclick="__doPostBack('order_summary_remove_product', 'RetailerProductID_137'); return false;">Remove</a></td>
            </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: Ah. Looks like it's not the first instance of that class. Posting the html above...

Comment: got it with this: document.querySelector('td.product-price').innerHTML.
Noticed it works with .textContent at the end too. Wondr if one is better than the other

Comment: thanks all for the helpful advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> document.querySelector('td.product-price').innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.product-price')[1].innerHTML
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uKFMW/)**

`querySelector` only returns the first match, while `querySelectorAll` returns all of them (hence the `[1]`) notation to get the second element. You can also use `textContent`
 in place of `innerHTML` as it works a little faster, but you won't notice much of a difference in your case.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.product-price')
```

will return an array of elements with the given class.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.product-price')[n]
```

will give you (n+1)th element with the class

`.innerHTML` : will give you html content inside it, i.e. even the tags.

`.textContent` : will give you only text, no html tags.

Answer (score 0):

What you want are the properties: innerText and innerHTML.
But you are selecting the correct item. You select all elements that have the product-price class, and the title of the table has that class.
I recommend you first to ensure you select the correct item.